# How can i multiply two registers and store them in a different register?

Tags: assembly, x86, multiplication

So I am attempting and failing to make a GCD program for assembly language(Intel x86, using NASM).  Where I keep getting compiler errors is when trying to multiply two registers.  I have users values stored in the registers ebx, ecx, and edx.  I want to multiply all 3
& store the product of ebx and ecx in ebx, then multiply ebx and edx, and store in ebx, and display the result.  Im attempting to do this by using this code
        `imul    ebx, ebx, ecx`
        `imul    ebx, ebx, edx`
Is this not a valid way to multiply registers?

Comment: If seeing my entire program will help someone help me, I'm more than happy to post it!  I left it out for now as I think this is most likely a simple question that would only be complicated by my clunky ugly code.

Comment: Oops, those are not valid.

Comment: Your title says "two registers", your content "three registers" whats true?  I programmed assembler long ago, but IIRC CPU's simply can't operate with three registers at once. Physically. Maybe this is why your're getting errors, which you should at least add to the question. `JMP BACK` `AND TRY AGAIN`. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 3 operand version of `imul` only takes an immediate as third operand. Luckily, you can use the 2 operand version, since one of your operands is the same as the destination. Thus:

```
imul    ebx, ecx ; ebx *= ecx
imul    ebx, edx ; ebx *= edx
```

will do what you want.

Comment: @JamieJackson - Perhaps it would be a good idea to download the [Intel reference manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). Problems like this are covered in more detail than you'd find anywhere else.